# Can't inject Router into HttpInterceptor (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I want to inject the Angular Router into my HttpInterceptor. Unfortunately, the following error is thrown in the browser console:

> TypeError: this.router is undefined

I've added this to my constructor as usual:

```
constructor (private router: Router) {

}
```

Additionally, I did the following in my providers array inside the app.module.ts:

```
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: MyService,
  multi: true,
  deps: [Router]
}
```

I want to use the current url inside an if statement in my error handler to provide specific functionalities for different routes:

```
myErrorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
   if (this.router.url === 'test') {
     // do something
   } else {
     return throwError(error).pipe(
       // do something
     );
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give some more context? the code in the question looks fine.

Comment: @Lemon I have updated my question. I want to get the current route (url) in my interceptor and use it within an error handler.

Comment: @Codehan25 Did you manage to solve this problem?  I am encountering the same issue with the same setup.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from another relevant topic: [Angular 6 Service is undefined after injecting in Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165619/angular-6-service-is-undefined-after-injecting-in-interceptor)

Basically, the injected constructor variable is not available from the function you pass to the `catchError` function. You need to access the `router` directly in your ´intercept method´ like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            // this.router is defined here
        })
    );
}
```

The problem seems to lie within the `catchError`.  If you print the current scope `this` in both the `intercept` and `catchError` functions you get **MyInterceptor** and **CatchSubscriber** respectively.  `this.router` is not available from the CatchSubscriber.  You can still use separate functions by adding a private method in your interceptor class:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.handleError(errorResponse);
        })
    );
}

private handleError(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
     // this.router is defined here
}
```

To summarize:

```
catchError(this.handleError)  // does not work because of different scope

catchError(err => this.handleError(err))  // works because of same scope
```

Comment: this saved me from some headache.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done this? Too obvious?

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

Comment: Sure :) I think there is something special with Interceptors but I can‘t find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using injector.

```
constructor(inj: Injector) {
this.router = inj.get(AuthService) }
```

You should note that it is not possible to import a service that contains httpClientModule to avoid a cyclic dependency.